# Criar uma nova coluna em data frame com função condicional

Tags: r, if, dplyr

Eu gostaria de criar uma nova variável, a Segmentof, a partir dos valores da variável Coseg.

Meu data frame segue essa estrutura

```
data= data.frame( conta=c(11111, 32412, 457845, 754689,58486),
Coseg= c("AD", "B2C","AD","B2C","AD"))
```

E eu gostaria que fosse

```
data= data.frame( conta=c(11111, 32412, 457845, 754689,58486),
                  Coseg= c("AD", "B2C","AD","B2C","AD"),
                  Segmentof =c("Adivisor", "Business to Company","Adivisor","Business to Company","Adivisor")
```

Eu tentei usar a seguinte função

```
Filtro_df<- mutate(data,
                   Segmentof= ifelse(Coseg %in% c("AD"), "Advisor", Coseg),
                   Segmentof= ifelse(Coseg %in% c("B2C"), "Business to Company",Coseg))
```

Porém a variável Segmentof acaba sendo sobrescrita, e os valores acabam sendo OU "Advisor" OU "Business to Company"

Answer (score 3):

Use o [`case_when`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html)

```
Filtro_df <- data %>%
  mutate(
    Segmentof = case_when(
      Coseg == "AD" ~ "Advisor",
      Coseg == "B2C" ~ "Business to Company",
      TRUE ~ Coseg)
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

Usando a função [`str_replace_all`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_replace.html) do pacote `stringr`:

```
data$Segmentof = stringr::str_replace_all(data$Coseg, c("AD" = "Adivisor", "B2C" = "Business to Company"))
```

Também é possível utilizar o pacote `dplyr` com `mutate`, deixando a resposta mais parecida com a de Paulo:

```
data = mutate(data, Segmentof = stringr::str_replace_all(Coseg, c("AD" = "Adivisor", "B2C" = "Business to Company")))
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma solução com `match` para obter um índice numérico que diga qual dos casos é cada valor de `Coseg`. Depois usa-se esse índice para atribuir os valores da nova coluna.

```r
data <- data.frame(conta=c(11111, 32412, 457845, 754689,58486),
                   Coseg= c("AD", "B2C","AD","B2C","AD"))

i <- match(data$Coseg, c("AD", "B2C"))
data$Segmentof <- NA_character_
data$Segmentof <- c("Adivisor", "Business to Company")[i]
data
#>    conta Coseg           Segmentof
#> 1  11111    AD            Adivisor
#> 2  32412   B2C Business to Company
#> 3 457845    AD            Adivisor
#> 4 754689   B2C Business to Company
#> 5  58486    AD            Adivisor
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Testes

Como há três soluções diferentes, a do [Paulo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/571235/82237), a do [Ricardo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/571244/82237) e a acima, aqui vai um teste comparativo de desempenho.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(tidyverse)
  library(microbenchmark)
})

so_test <- function(x, n = 15) {
  f1 <- function(data) {
    data %>% mutate(Segmentof = 
                      case_when(Coseg == "AD" ~ "Advisor", 
                                Coseg == "B2C" ~ "Business to Company"))
  }
  f2 <- function(data) {
    data$Segmentof <- stringr::str_replace_all(data$Coseg, c("AD" = "Adivisor", "B2C" = "Business to Company"))
    data
  }
  f3 <- function(data) {
    i <- match(data$Coseg, c("AD", "B2C"))
    data$Segmentof <- NA_character_
    data$Segmentof <- c("Adivisor", "Business to Company")[i]
    data
  }
  
  out <- lapply(seq.int(n), \(k) {
    y <- x
    for(i in 1:k) y <- rbind(y, y)
    mb <- microbenchmark(
      Paulo = f1(y),
      Ricardo = f2(y),
      Rui = f3(y)
    )
    agg <- aggregate(time ~ expr, mb, median)
    agg$dim <- nrow(y)
    agg
  })
  do.call(rbind, out)
}

result <- so_test(data)
str(result)
#> 'data.frame':    45 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ expr: Factor w/ 3 levels "Paulo","Ricardo",..: 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 ...
#>  $ time: num  1502252 254301 23052 1291052 224901 ...
#>  $ dim : int  10 10 10 20 20 20 40 40 40 80 ...

ggplot(result, aes(dim, time, colour = expr)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = "log10") +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

`ifelse` opera sobre todos os elemento do vetor. Ao usar duas vezes, o resultado será sobrescrito:

```
Coseg <- c("AD", "B2C")

Filtro_df <- ifelse(Coseg == "AD", "Advisor", Coseg)
Filtro_df
#> [1] "Advisor" "B2C"

Filtro_df <- ifelse(Coseg == "B2C", "Business to Company", Coseg)
Filtro_df
#> [1] "AD"                  "Business to Company"
```

O uso adequado no seu caso, em que há apenas duas alternativas, é usar uma vez:

```
ifelse(Coseg == "AD", "Advisor", "Business to Company")
#> [1] "Advisor"             "Business to Company"

# OU

ifelse(Coseg == "B2C", "Business to Company", "Advisor")
#> [1] "Advisor"             "Business to Company"
```

Usando seu exemplo e com a sintaxe do *tidyverse*:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  conta = c(11111, 32412, 457845, 754689, 58486),
  Coseg = c("AD", "B2C", "AD", "B2C", "AD"))

df %<>% mutate(Segmentof = ifelse(Coseg == "AD", "Advisor", "Business to Company"))

df
#>    conta Coseg           Segmentof
#> 1  11111    AD             Advisor
#> 2  32412   B2C Business to Company
#> 3 457845    AD             Advisor
#> 4 754689   B2C Business to Company
#> 5  58486    AD             Advisor
```

Se estiver lidando com dados muito grande, uma alternativa mais eficiente é a `fifelse` ("fast ifelse") do pacote *data.table*:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data)

data[, Segmentof := fifelse(Coseg == "AD", "Adivisor", "Business to Company")]
```

## Teste

Atualizando o [teste de eficiência das diferentes soluções feita por Rui Barradas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/571332/117168).

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

teste <- function(n, ...) {

  f1 <- function(df) {
    df <- df %>%
      mutate(Segmentof = case_when(
        Coseg == "AD" ~ "Advisor",
        Coseg == "B2C" ~ "Business to Company",
        TRUE ~ Coseg))
  }
  f2 <- function(df) {
    df <- df %>%
      mutate(Segmentof = str_replace_all(Coseg,
        c("AD" = "Adivisor", "B2C" = "Business to Company")))
  }
  f3 <- function(df) {
    i <- match(df$Coseg, c("AD", "B2C"))
    df$Segmentof <- NA_character_
    df$Segmentof <- c("Adivisor", "Business to Company")[i]
  }
  f4 <- function(df) {
    df <- df %>%
      mutate(Segmentof = ifelse(Coseg == "AD", "Adivisor", "Business to Company"))
  }
  f5 <- function(df) {
    setDT(df)[, Segmentof := fifelse(Coseg == "AD", "Adivisor", "Business to Company")]
  }

  y <- data.frame(
    conta = sample(11111:99999, n, TRUE),
    Coseg = sample(c("AD", "B2C"), n, TRUE))

  microbenchmark(
    `dplyr::case_when`= f1(y),
    `stringr::str_replace_all`= f2(y),
    `match`= f3(y),
    `ifelse` = f4(y),
    `data.table::fifelse` = f5(y),
    ...)
}

ns <- 10^(3:7)
res <- lapply(ns, teste, times = 20)
res <- rbindlist(setNames(res, ns), idcol = "n")[, n := as.integer(n)]

ggplot(res, aes(n, time/1e6, color = expr, fill = expr, label = expr)) +
  geom_point(alpha = .5) +
  geom_smooth() +
  geom_text(aes(1e7, V1/1e6),
    res[n == 1e7, mean(time), expr],
    hjust = 0, nudge_x = .05) +
  scale_x_log10(expand = expansion(add = c(.1, .9))) +
  scale_y_log10() +
  labs(x = "linhas", y = "milisegundos") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas eu considero a solução de Rui Barradas com `match` mais interessante. É eficiente, independe de pacotes extras e serve para qualquer número de substituições.